# how to design schema in dynamodb for a reading comprehension quiz application where data would be heavy?

Tags: amazon-web-services, database-design, amazon-dynamodb, schema

Pls check the uml diagram

What I want to know is if there is 30quest and their options in section 1 ,20question in section 2,30question in section 3, how should i keep in the table as RC passages would have 300-400 words, plus the questions,options it would be around 7-800 words per question.

So each question should have one row in the table or , testwise i should have different columns of section and all question, option should be saved in json format in one column(item for dynamodb)?

Answer (score 1):

I would follow these rules for DynamoDB table design:

1. Definitely keep everything in one table. It's rare for one application to need multiple tables. It is OK to have different items (rows) in DynamoDB represent different kinds of objects.
2. Start by identifying your access patterns, that is, what are the questions you need to ask of your data? This will determine your choice of partition key, sort key, and indexes.
3. Try to pick a [partition key](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/choosing-the-right-dynamodb-partition-key/) that will result in object accesses being spread somewhat evenly over your different partitions.

If you will have lots of different tests, with accesses spread somewhat evenly over the tests, then TestID could be a good partition key. You will probably want to pull up all the tests for a given instructor, so you could have a column InstructorID with a [global secondary index](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GSI.html) pointing back to the primary key attributes.

Your [sort key](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/bp-sort-keys.html) could be heterogenous--it could be different depending on whether the item is a question or a student's answer. For questions, the sort key could be `QuestionID` with the content of the question stored as other attributes. For question options it could be `QuestionID#OptionID`, with something like an OptionDescription attribute for the content of the option. Keep in mind that it's OK to have sparse attributes--not every item needs something populated for every attribute, and it's OK to have attributes that are meaningless for many items. For answers, your sort key could be `QuestionID#OptionID#StudentID`, with the content of the student's answer stored as a StudentAnswer attribute.

Here is a guide on [DynamoDB best practices](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/best-practices.html). For something more digestible, search in YouTube for "aws reinvent dynamo rick houlihan." Rick Houlihan has some good talks about data modeling in DynamoDB. Here are a couple, and one more on data modeling:

1. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6yqfmXiZTlM&list=PL_EDAAla3DXWy4GW_gnmaIs0PFvEklEB7
2. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HaEPXoXVf2k
3. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DIQVJqiSUkE

Answer (score 0):

The better approach is to store each question and its option as a row in DynamoDB Table . Definitely will not suggest , the second approach of storing the question and answer as a JSON is definitely not advisable as  the maximum size of a DynamoDb Item is 400 Kb. In such scenarios , using a document database is much more helpful.

Also try to come up with the type of queries that you will be running . Some of the typical ones are

1. Get all questions in a section by SectionID
2. Get the details of a Question by Question Id
3. Get all questions

If you can provide some more information , I could guide you in data modelling 
Also I did not see the UML diagram

Comment: Yes there would be query with CRUD in this three way, get question by id, get questions by section id, so should I use mongo/documentDB to save all the question, answer in json format ?

Answer (score 0):

The following is  my suggestion.Create the DynamoDB table

1. Store each sectionId , question and its option as a row in DynamoDB Table
2. Partition Key :- SectionID , Sort Key :-  QuestionId
3. Create a GSI on the table with Partition Key :- QuestionId, Sort Key :-  OptionId

Comment: Thought of the same but if one section has 100 questions it might exceed 400kb size in dynamodb item max size. that's what I bothering me. so may be I have to keep one question and it's options in one row in dynamoDB. but why i don't want to do that is, it may require too much if database connection... for every questn I have to call an API and get it from database. SO is it ok to go to DB every now and then?

Comment: Yes... As long as you use Query  api to query the data